# Jhipster what does the "query" query string option do?

Tags: java, spring, jhipster

I was looking at the frontend code generated by jhipster and found a query string option that is generated by the generator.The option is there to be sent to the API whenever you are listing all the entities. Unfortunately, the option, which is `query` was never used. I'm just wondering what it might be used for. I'll appreciate your help thanks.The code below shows my point of interest inside of my entity service. `params.set('query', req,query)` is what I need the purpose of explained.

```
query(req?: any): Observable<Response> {
    let options = this.createRequestOption(req);
    return this.http.get(this.resourceUrl, options)
        .map((res: any) => this.convertResponse(res))
    ;
}

private createRequestOption(req?: any): BaseRequestOptions {
    let options: BaseRequestOptions = new BaseRequestOptions();
    if (req) {
        let params: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
        params.set('page', req.page);
        params.set('size', req.size);
        if (req.sort) {
            params.paramsMap.set('sort', req.sort);
        }
        params.set('query', req.query);

        options.search = params;
    }
    return options;
}
```

Comment: I thought it was related to the filtering [mecanism](http://www.jhipster.tech/entities-filtering/) and that we could use the criteria language in the query (e.g. `/languages?id.greaterThan=5&amp;attr1.contains=something&amp;attr2.specified=false`). But it is not.